# Logic for inserting into a database after Paypal payment (PHP. MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, paypal

I'm building an application with Codeigniter where the users can access a form to create their profile, after they fill the form they have to pay through Paypal and if the payment was successful the profile is created on the database.

How do I store the data submitted on the form so I can use it after the Paypal payment?

Should I insert it in the database when the user submit the form in the first place?
Should I use sessions?

The form includes multiple file inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Instant Payment Notification(IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

`Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, like fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.`

[Sample Codes](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)

Comment: First of all thanks for your response, I'm still having a hard time understanding the logic behind this, should I post the form then run the validation and if it was successful proceed to the payment, wait for the verification and then insert everything into the database?

Comment: Its like, buyer makes a purchase on your website, the transaction details are sent asynchronously (without hindering the checkout process) to your IPN listener code . Once IPN is received at your end, then your IPN listener code will have to process the request and then you insert into your database.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I still don't understand how to pass the information submitted in the form to the listener. If I'm understanding correctly I have to specify the listener's URL where the verification is going to arrive asynchronously and where the database insert is going to occur.

Comment: using this:

<input type="hidden" name = "return" value="your_ipn_listener_file_url" />

Answer (score 0):

Are you having SandBox account? Manage all you prior testing in Sandbox.

For receiving the data about the paypal payment you nees to install the library.
Here is the link -https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn

Set up the library files accordingly.

After this go to IPN simulator of your Sandbox Account on - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

try sending IPN .

Note - For testing IPN stimulation you will need live site, you can't test on localhost.

Comment: this should be a comment !